# which is the correct way to call method in iOS

Tags: objective-c, method-call

I have worked with iOS but exactly i am not getting What are the difference between this all methods,

Out of this which syntax should i use to call **MehodName** ?

```
 (1) [self MehodName];

 (2) [self performSelector:@selector(MehodName) withObject:nil];

 (3) [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(MehodName) withObject:nil];

 (4) [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(MehodName) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

 (5) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 
                                         (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
    [self MehodName];
});

  (6) dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self MehodName];       
});
```

***Please Help and Thanks in advance.***

Comment: They all have their uses. #1 is the standard way unless you have an appropriate reason to use the others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All the ways are correct ways depending on your requirement

(1) Executes the method on the same thread on which thread currently your code is executing. 
(may be background thread or a main thread).

(2)  1 and 2  are pretty same  but (2) has advantage that you can dynamically determine which selector to call at runtime.

(3) is same as [NSThread detachNewThread] it creates a new thread (means selector not executed on main thread)
generally used for webService image fetching etc.

(4) performs the selector on the main thread (generally used for performing UI changes)
  if method executed on this thread is too long or heavy it hangs the application for that duration as that method is executed on priority

(5)dispatch async used for doing the task which can be done asynchronously which in your case is using (global queue which are concurrent queues) (not executed on main thread in current case) (like heavy database insertion) background image fetch  , those methods which gives you callback later  on completion

(6) dispatch sync executes the method synchronously (in your case on main thread) (genrally used for login operations , validation etc.).

Comment: Your descriptions for 5 and 6 are slightly misleading to someone new to this. You sort of imply that dispatch async is for background and dispatch sync is for main thread. Both sync and async can be used on both background and main threads. It all depends on which queue is passed in.

Comment: good explanation dude, but still i have doubt which syntax should i use if i want to fetch data from webService?

Comment: @rmaddy You are right but According to question (6) is using main thread and  (5) is using global queues which are concurrent queues

Comment: @Krunal if you are fetching important data like (validating user login) then use performselectoronmainthread otherwise for image fetching like time taking thing use performselectroinbackground

Comment: In which case it creates a new thread for execution ?

Comment: - (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg
This method creates a new thread in your application, putting your application into multithreaded mode if it was not already.
NSObject Class reference  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#jumpTo_45

Comment: How to stop or cancel this thread on click of button? is there any way ?

Comment: I am not getting ur point , if you want this functionality to cancel operations  use NSOperationsQueue and NSOperations

Answer (score 3):

Essentially #1 and #2 are the same. Use #1 under normal conditions.

Items #3 and #5 are essentially the same. #5 uses GCD and is more flexible. Use these to ensure the code is called on a background thread.

Items #4 and #6 are essentially the same. Again, #6 uses GCD and is more flexible. Use these from code on a background thread to run the method on the main thread. This is usually done when the code to be called is UI related.

Comment: you says Items #3 and #5 are essentially the same and #4 and #6 also.. then why apple is giving us 2 syntax is there any minor difference between the two ?

Comment: @Krunal what exactly are you trying to do?  What is your goal?  If you are learning how to call methods in general, #1 is the way to go. Forget all of the other options.

Comment: 5 and 6 are newer library features (grand central dispatch - GCD) provided by Apple. 2, 3, and 4 are older ways provided by `NSObject`. The older ways are very limited. The called method can only have 0 or 1 parameter. The block-based GCD is far more flexible.

Comment: my goal is i want to call a method, from above which syntax will give me best performance in main as well as in background thread?

Comment: @Krunal The answer is "it depends". Your question if a bit too vague to give the best answer. Each case is different and specific.

Comment: @Krunal for you, any option will give you the performance you need.

Comment: In which case it creates a new thread for execution ?

Answer (score 0):

All the methods mentioned above their own use cases. We can not say anyone of the way is better than other.

(1) - Method you called will executed in the main thread. Please don't execute long running codes in this methods.

(2) - This will give you flexibility to choose your method name in run time. You are passing method name as SEL object which can be determined in the run time. You can build your valid method names from NSString objects. There is limitations for passing parameters when you are using this type, you can only pass up to 2 parameters to this method call. You can only pass NSObject as parameters.

(3) - Methods will be executed in newly created thread. Since newly created is independent on main thread, you can run long running jobs in this method without affecting UI thread. Since compiler will create on demand threads for executing method, this approach is not advisable for background threading.

(4) - This is same as that of #1 method calling. Methods invocation using this approach will be executed in the main thread. But you can use this method for updating UI elements from the background thread. If you want to execute a method in main thread from where you stand in a background thread, you can use this approach.

(5) - It is GCD approach of method calling in Cocoa. In the #5 appraoch your method will be queued in one of the Global Queue (4 Global Queues for an application). All the jobs in the Global queues will be serially completes its execution. You can use #5 instead of #3 because GCD will handle it threads by itself, developer doesn't look after about the thread handling.

(6) - This is also a GCD approach, for executing methods in the main thread from background GCD thread. If the compiler stands in a background GCD queue you can perform jobs in main thread using this approach.

Hope every thing is clear for you....

Comment: in which method my object gets retained, in case if i pass object to method ?

Comment: All of the method calling will retain your parameter.